# Java Regex to Validate Full Name allow only Spaces and Letters

Tags: java, regex, validation

I want regex to validate for only letters and spaces. Basically this is to validate full name.  Ex: **Mr Steve Collins or Steve Collins**  I tried this regex.  "[a-zA-Z]+\.?" But didnt work. Can someone assist me please 
p.s. I use Java.

```
public static boolean validateLetters(String txt) {

    String regx = "[a-zA-Z]+\\.?";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
    return matcher.find();

}
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

What about:

- Peter Müller
- François Hollande
- Patrick O'Brian
- Silvana Koch-Mehrin

Validating names is a difficult issue, because valid names are not only consisting of the letters A-Z.

At least you should use the Unicode property for letters and add more special characters. A first approach could be e.g.:

```
String regx = "^[\\p{L} .'-]+$";
```

`\\p{L}` is a [Unicode Character Property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) that matches any kind of letter from any language

Comment: yes thats very true. This regex works perfectly. Smart one.thnx lot

Comment: (based on stema's answer) 

how about this one: 
`"^\pL+[\pL\pZ\pP]{0,}"` 

now all dash, dot and space are also in unicode

Comment: What does the "+" stand for?

Comment: @summers plus sign means one or more repetitions

Comment: `^[\\p{L}]+$` appears  to mach all types of spaces also. Does spaces also fall under Unicode Character category?

Comment: @AamirRizwan no, '\p{L}' contains only any kind of letters and no whitespace.

Comment: But it will consume `. ` as a name as well

Comment: @NickSikrier I don't get your point. Of course it does, as the `.` is explicitly mentioned in the character class and I require only at least one character. It will also match a single space and `'` and `-`. This answer is only a starting point for those who think that they need to judge what is a valid name. Feel free to add a "better" quantifier than `+` to request a minimum/maximum length, or check with lookaheads for character sequences that make no sense for you (But maybe for the guy with the "exotic" name).

Comment: @stema I am sorry, as a starting point, of course, it is a good example. Anyway, in most cases I suppose, it should, at least, start and finish with a letter.

Comment: Strangely, this validates a name starting with spaces.

Comment: For those wondering why this doesn't validate names in Indian languages, you need this form `"^[\\p{L}\\p{M} .'-]+$"`.

Answer (score 18):

try this regex (allowing Alphabets, Dots, Spaces):

```
"^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}[\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\s]{0,}$" //regular
"^\pL+[\pL\pZ\pP]{0,}$" //unicode
```

This will also ensure DOT never comes at the start of the name.

Comment: Do i have to use \\s for Java ?

Comment: "\s" Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed

Comment: I trid this. But it returns true even when i enter numbers.

Comment: try this:
"^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}[\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\s]{0,}$"

Comment: it works fine except these cases. Mr.3Steve Collins, Mr.Steve 44Collins, Mr.Steve Collins44

Comment: I Managed to fix the issue using stema's regex. Please look at the thread again. String regx = "^[\\p{L} .'-]+$"; But I appreciate your effort. Thnx again

Comment: `SOME GUY` matches this regex

Answer (score 13):

For those who use java/android and struggle with this matter try:

```
"^\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\p{Z}\\p{P}]{0,}"
```

This works with names like

- José Brasão

Comment: I dont know much about regex but, I want to know is this regex stop numbers too

Answer (score 13):

You could even try this expression `^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$` for checking a string with only letters and spaces (nothing else).

For me it worked. Hope it works for you as well.

Or go through this piece of code once:

```
    CharSequence inputStr = expression;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(new String ("^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$"));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if(matcher.matches())
    {
         //if pattern matches
    }
    else
    {
         //if pattern does not matches
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

please try this regex (allow only Alphabets and space)

> "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*"

if you want it for IOS then,

```
NSString *yourstring = @"hello";

NSString *Regex = @"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*";
NSPredicate *TestResult = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",Regex];

if ([TestResult evaluateWithObject:yourstring] == true)
{
    // validation passed
}
else
{
    // invalid name
}
```

Comment: whats the difference between `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*` and `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+` ? did you know ?

Comment: * mean optional(zero or more) and + meaning more then one.
so suppose you check with single character then `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*` will return true but for `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+` returns false for that you need 2 characters.

note: you can use `[a-zA-Z]+` instead of `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*` both are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

**Regex pattern for matching only alphabets and white spaces:**

```
String regexUserName = "^[A-Za-z\\s]+$";
```

Answer (score 2):

**Accept only character with space :-**

```
 if (!(Pattern.matches("^[\\p{L} .'-]+$", name.getText()))) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid character", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    name.setFocusable(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

My personal choice is:
`^\p{L}+[\p{L}\p{Pd}\p{Zs}']*\p{L}+$|^\p{L}+$`, Where:

`^\p{L}+` - It should start with 1 or more letters.

`[\p{Pd}\p{Zs}'\p{L}]*` - It can have letters, space character (including invisible), dash or hyphen characters and ' in any order 0 or more times.

`\p{L}+$` - It should finish with 1 or more letters.

`|^\p{L}+$` - Or it just should contain 1 or more letters (It is done to support single letter names).

Support for dots (full stops) was dropped, as in British English it can be dropped in Mr or Mrs, for example.

Comment: Shouldn't it support Hindi names as well? like रोहित शर्मा . Any language character should be accepted right? But it's failing to identify Hindi type script Devanagari as Language character.

Comment: Unfortunately, it works correctly.
Devanagari contains zero-width joiner, as it is complex script.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner

Answer (score 1):

To validate for only letters and spaces, try this

```
String name1_exp = "^[a-zA-Z]+[\-'\s]?[a-zA-Z ]+$";
```

Comment: If i want to validate the number of characters what might be the code  ?

Answer (score 1):

Validates such values as:
***"", "FIR", "FIR ", "FIR LAST"***

```
/^[A-z]*$|^[A-z]+\s[A-z]*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out.

```
String name validation only accept alphabets and spaces
public static boolean validateLetters(String txt) {

    String regx = "^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
    return matcher.find();

}
```

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer? This doesn't match `Peter Müller` or
 `François Hollande`

Answer (score 1):

To support language like Hindi which can contain /p{Mark} as well in between language characters.
My solution is `^[\p{L}\p{M}]+([\p{L}\p{Pd}\p{Zs}'.]*[\p{L}\p{M}])+$|^[\p{L}\p{M}]+$`

You can find all the test cases for this here 
https://regex101.com/r/3XPOea/1/tests

Answer (score 0):

@amal. This code will match your requirement. Only letter and space in between will be allow, no number. The text begin with any letter and could have space in between only. "^" denotes the beginning of the line and "$" denotes end of the line.

```
public static boolean validateLetters(String txt) {

    String regx = "^[a-zA-Z ]+$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
    return matcher.find();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public static boolean userNameValidation(String name){

return name.matches("(?i)(^[a-z])((?![? .,'-]$)[ .]?[a-z]){3,24}$");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java, you can use below for Name validation which uses Alpha (Letters) + Spaces (Blanks or tabs)

```
"[^\\\p{Alpha}\\\p{Blank}]"
```

Can get a [reference from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#:%7E:text=A%20regex%20pattern%20matches%20a,require%20using%20(%20)%20as%20metacharacters.) for ASCII values also.