# Regular expression to allow just single blank space after a character or word

Tags: jquery, regex

This is what I have done so far,

```
$('.name').keyup(function () {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z' ]+( [A-Za-z' ]+)*$/g, function (str) {
        return '';
    }));
});
```

The above expression allows me to enter A-Z and ' and space. But I want only one space afer a character or word.

```
Ex. Hello World is ok
but Hello  World should not be accepted.
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/3Vn3P/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.name').keyup(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.val($th.val().replace(/(\s{2,})|[^a-zA-Z']/g, ' '));
    $th.val($th.val().replace(/^\s*/, ''));
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HUV7/)

Comment: i can still add multiple spaces.

Comment: Sorry, was my mistake, I've paste wrong code, try again plase

Comment: when i enter character like ,./\] space is left at the start...try entering ./]\ you will find 1 blank spaces at the start...

Comment: you there..can my issue be sorted!

Comment: Yes its perfect other things are ok just wanted to know how can I remove the space in the begining..

Comment: thats better...one thing I cant use my back arrow key to go back in string .. can that be sorted too..

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a solution for this issue. Since this code changes the whole input content on every 'keyup event', we lost cursor position. So I think the only way to edit text will be with backspace.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts and time for the answer...however if you come up with the solution please do let me know.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach might be better. Just replace repeated spaces with a single space:

```
.replace(/\s+/, ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could simply replace repeated spaces:

```
str.replace(/[ ]{2,}/, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your inner most code part, try replacing "replace(/[^a-zA-Z' ]+( [A-Za-z' ]+)" with "replace(/[^a-zA-Z' ]+( [A-Za-z']+)"

I got this hint from this post: [Regular expression to allow single space after character or word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056431/regular-expression-to-allow-single-space-after-character-or-word) so you may want to read that too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take out the space at the end of your brackets.

```
[^a-zA-Z']+( [A-Za-z']+)
```

Although I would consider putting the space at the end of the first word so you can actually type in real time.

```
$('.name').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        $th.val( $th.val().replace(/([^a-zA-Z'] )+([A-Za-z']+)*$/g, function(str) {  return ''; } ) );
    });
```

Comment: user should not be able to add ,./\][ these characters as well...also on entering 2 space both the space are getting deleted..

Comment: how can i delete just the extra space entered by the user. Also the input tobe limited to a-z and '