# Regex for a name and number dart

Tags: regex, dart

I need to validate a form that a user provides their name and a number. I have a regex that is supposed to make sure the name contains only letters and nothing else and also for the number input i need to make sure only numbers are in the field.
The code I have looks like

```
 validator: (value) => value.isEmpty
                        ? 'Enter Your Name'
                        : RegExp(
                                '!@#<>?":_``~;[]\|=-+)(*&^%1234567890')
                            ? 'Enter a Valid Name'
                            : null,
```

can i get a regex expression that validates a name in such a way if any special character or number is inputted it becomes wrong meaning only letters are valid and another that validates a number in such a way if an alphabetical letter or any special character is inputted it becomes wrong meaning only the input of a number is valid

Comment: Looks like you wanted `RegExp(r'[!@#<>?":_\`~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%0-9-]').hasMatch(value)`. You need to use a raw string literal, put `-` at the end and escape `]` and ``\`` chars, then check if there is a match with `.hasMatch(value)`. `[0123456789]` = `[0-9]`.

Comment: This works for the Name RegExp. Can you explain for the number one. In this one, the user is presented with the number keyboard so some characters are not important as such. I have just copied the name Regex and pasted it here but removed `0-9` in order to be able to input the numbers. Problem is, when a space is inserted, it still counts it as a value. How can i correct this.

Comment: Add `\s` - `r'[!@#<>?":_\`~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%\s-]'`

Comment: Yes. This works. You can add the answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems to me you want

```
RegExp(r'[!@#<>?":_`~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%0-9-]').hasMatch(value)
```

Note that you need to use a raw string literal, put `-` at the end and escape `]` and `\` chars inside the resulting *character class*, then check if there is a match with `.hasMatch(value)`. Notre also that `[0123456789]` is equal to `[0-9]`.

As for the second pattern, you can remove the digit range from the regex (as you need to allow it) and add a `\s` pattern (`\s` matches any whitespace char) to disallow whitespace in the input:

```
RegExp(r'[!@#<>?":_`~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%\s-]').hasMatch(value)
```

Comment: Some people combine their last names after marriage, making their names include a hyphen. Do you know how to make a hyphen/dash ( - ) an exception?

Comment: Do not forget to add / into the RegExp(r'[!@#<>?"/·:_`~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%0-9-]')

Answer (score 25):

Create a static final field for the RegExp to avoid creating a new instance every time a value is checked. Creating a RegExp is expensive.

```
static final RegExp nameRegExp = RegExp('[a-zA-Z]'); 
    // or RegExp(r'\p{L}'); // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters 
static final RegExp numberRegExp = RegExp(r'\d');
```

Then use it like

```
validator: (value) => value.isEmpty 
    ? 'Enter Your Name'
    : (nameRegExp.hasMatch(value) 
        ? null 
        : 'Enter a Valid Name');
```

Comment: Both are not working. In the question I specified I need something that will not accept anything else other than alphabetical letters, for the name. And for the number input, numbers only not a special character or anything else. This regex thing is awfully stressful

Comment: eg. for the name if it is **gunter zochbauer**  if a comma is present somewhere it becomes wrong

Comment: You demanded "only letters". Did you check the commented out alternative. If this us not what you want please formulate your question more precise.

Comment: i have edited the original question to further explain it. Apologies

Comment: I still don't think it is unclear how my answer does not answer your question. `RegExp('[a-zA-Z\ ]')` validates to `true` for my name.

Answer (score 8):

Base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806080) and this information:

> \p{L} or \p{Letter}: any kind of letter from any language.

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

The regex for a name validation:

```
RegExp(r"^[\p{L} ,.'-]*$",
      caseSensitive: false, unicode: true, dotAll: true)
  .hasMatch(my_name)
```

Comment: Awesome, even allows hyphen between names

Comment: This was the only one that worked for my case. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me

```
void main() {
  RegExp nameRegex = RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
  RegExp numberRegex = RegExp(r"^\d+$");
  print(nameRegex.hasMatch("Ggggg"));
  print(numberRegex.hasMatch("999"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should also work.
The parser is a constant expression, it is fast and does not consume much memory.

```dart
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/alpha1.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/digit1.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/eof.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/many1.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/predicate.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/skip_while.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/terminated.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parsing.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  const name = Terminated(
    Many1(
      Terminated(Alpha1(), SkipWhile(isWhitespace)),
    ),
    Eof(),
  );

  const number = Terminated(Digit1(), Eof());

  final input1 = 'John  Snow '.trim();
  final r1 = tryParse(name.parse, input1).result;
  if (r1 != null) {
    final fullName = r1.value;
    print('Name is valid: $input1');
    print('First name: ${fullName.first}');
    if (fullName.length > 1) {
      print('Second name: ${fullName[1]}');
    }
  }

  final input2 = ' 123 '.trim();
  final r2 = tryParse(number.parse, input2).result;
  if (r2 != null) {
    print('Number is valid: $input2');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Name is valid: John  Snow
First name: John
Second name: Snow
Number is valid: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//\$ <- helps to exclude *, -, " and other characters
// so nameInputRegex.hasMatch.("alex-") will return false

get nameInputRegex => "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,$maxNameLength}\$";
```