# Java - Scanner doesn't read string with space (Solved)

Tags: java, regex, string, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to allow an input that is only made with characters a-zA-Z and also haves space. Example: **"Chuck Norris".**
What happens with the code below is that the  scanner `input.next()` doesn't allow the mentioned example input string.

I expect this output: `Success!` but this is the actual output: `Again:`

```
try {
    String input_nome = input.next();            // Source of the problem

    if (input_nome.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
        System.out.print("Success!");
        break;
    } else {
        System.err.print("Again: ");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

### SOLUTION

The source of the problem is the used scanner method.

```
String input_nome = input.next();            // Incorrect scanner method
String input_nome = input.nextLine();        // Correct scanner method
```

**Explanation:** *https://stackoverflow.com/a/22458766/11860800*

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers your code works fine so the issue is not related to your reg exp pattern if you get the wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String t = "Chuck Norris";

t.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")

Does in fact return true. Check for your input that it actually is "Chuck Norris", and make sure the space is not some weird character. Also instead of space, you can use \s. I also recommend 101regex.com

Comment: Thank you for your perspective! It stopped me from focusing only on the regular expression and realize that problem might be the scanner 

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link :
[Java Regex to Validate Full Name allow only Spaces and Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805555/java-regex-to-validate-full-name-allow-only-spaces-and-letters)

you can use the below Regular Expression

```
String regx = "^[\\p{L} .'-]+$";
```

This should work for all scenarios and unicode.